# Switch grouped axis on Excel chart

Tags: vba, excel

I have a chart of type `xlColumnClustered` and I want to switch the x and y axis.  Problem is that the axis is grouped.

My data looks like this:

```
Country Permenant   Flat        1%
                    Appartment  0%
                    House       2%
                    Shaq        0%
        Temporary   Flat        2%
                    Appartment  9%
                    House       1%
                    Shaq        0%
State   Permenant   Flat        8%
                    Appartment  13%
                    House       30%
                    Shaq        5%
        Temporary   Flat        6%
                    Appartment  0%
                    House       2%
                    Shaq        0%
```

In `ggplot` the command I would need is coord_flip(), it does this, does vba have any functionality similar to this?:

[image]

My code currently looks like this:

```
Sub insert_housing()

    Dim strRange As String
    Dim rngChart As Range
    Dim myChart As Chart

    'Just grabbing the data, nothing to see here
    sheet_name = "Sheet2"

    With Sheets(sheet_name)
        StartRow = .Range("D10000").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row
        EndRow = .Range("D10000").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Sheets(sheet_name).Activate
    Sheets(sheet_name).Range("$A$" & CStr(StartRow) & ":$D$" & CStr(EndRow)).Select

    'Probably start reading here
    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered).Chart

    With myChart
        .ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 6
        .HasTitle = True
        .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlPrimary) = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Frustrating Graphic of Housing"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "stuff"

        .HasAxis(xlValue, xlPrimary) = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

So to be clear, I'd like to see the grouped x axis on the y axis, y axis on the x axis.

What have i tried?

- Switch Row/column (this just gives me catagories such as "Country Permenant   Flat" in the legend, and a single bar for this, it doesn't visually rotate the graph)
- Playing with the data source and trying to manually adjust the axis
- The accepted solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e4844e3-7ef4-48ee-a475-2707df307f70/excel-vba-swap-x-and-y-series?forum=isvvba)
- I've also trawled numerous other sites in an attempt to solve this

Can anyone shed any light on how to put a grouped axis on the y axis in Excel VBA?

Comment: You can't change chart type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not change chart type and use 2D plot?

This would yield:

[image: Data]

Code recorded for this was:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet6!$A$1:$D$16")
```

Which you can tidy into something like the following, to get rid of the `.Select`

```
Dim c As Chart
Set c = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered).Chart
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet6!$A$1:$D$16")
```